# lat lon coordinates (WGS84) conversion to local x, y plane

Tags: coordinate-transformation, proj, wgs84, proj4js, pyproj

Currently I'm trying the following: I have points from google earth (WGS84) which I want to transform to a local x,y coordinate system: a tangential plane with y positive from south to north and x positive from west to east.

There is no need for the plane to be part of a global coordinate system more than the relation (x=0, y=0) = (lat,lon). The scale at which I'm working is in the order of say 100 kilometers (maximum of for example 200 km's). Very small errors (due to for example the curvature of the earth) are acceptable.

I have relatively little understanding of this topic as of yet. Can anybody help me out? Where would I need to look for example.

Thanks!

Comment: I would also like to know how to do this, and I found a library called Proj (aka Proj4) that does this sort of stuff, but I'm not sure how to use it so I posted a more detailed version of your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147814/how-to-convert-utm-coordinate-to-cartesian-coordinate-relative-to-an-earth-tange

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the answer mathematically but have found that the package basemap (of the mpl_toolkit) should help with this respect (from wgs84 to a transverse mercator projection).